# Mi barra de navegación con bootsrap y Jade no se muestra

Tags: bootstrap, nodejs, jade

Tengo un problema con mi barra de navegación con bootstrap y Jade, simplemente no funciona y si la hago en otro diferente a layout.jade me sale como si el contenido del nav y del index estuviese junto. ¿Algún consejo?
Agradezco mucho la comprensión, soy nueva con Jade, node.js y demás.

archivo *layout.jade*

```
 doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset='UTF-8')
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', type="text/css", href='/stylesheets/normalize.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', type="text/css", href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.css")
  body
    block content
      #navbar.navbar-collapse.collapse
      // Static navbar
      nav.navbar.navbar-default
        .container-fluid
          .navbar-header
            button.navbar-toggle.collapsed(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#navbar', aria-expanded='false', aria-controls='navbar')
              span.sr-only Toggle navigation
              span.icon-bar
              span.icon-bar
              span.icon-bar
            a.navbar-brand(href='#') Kitties
          #navbar.navbar-collapse.collapse
            ul.nav.navbar-nav
              li.active
                a(href='/') Home
                a(href='/about') About
                a(href='/contact') Contact

          // /.nav-collapse
        // /.container-fluid
        .container
        h1 Hello, #{title}
        block content
        hr
        footer
            p © 2017
    script(src='javascripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js')
    script(src='javascripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/bootstrap.js')
    script(src='javascripts/bootstrap.min.js')
```

Mi archivo *index.jade*

```
extends layout

block content


    .container
        h1 Welcome to #{title}

        p
        | This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.
        p
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de bootstrap estáis utilizando? Y ¿Qué es exactamente lo no funciona, el compilador de jade por alguna falla de sintaxis o que no es el resultado esperado en la vista?